# Delete column/index in Parse through code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to delete an entire column in the object table in Parse.com?
For example I have a column with name "Example" among other columns and I trying to get rid of it and all of the values under it.

I've tried the deleteInBackground() and deleteAtIndex() commands but they only delete entire rows or one cell. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the web interface to select the target class and drop the column (this is a manual operation, there is no provided API to do it).